# python syntax error (s for s in X if not in Z)

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, list-comprehension

ok this is not my code it's a code from GitHub there is a syntax error at this line

```
unique_items = np.unique(df_clean[item_columns].values).tolist()
items_headers = ['item-' + s for s in unique_items  if not in consumables]
```

I think it's a simple error but i am pretty noob in python (consumables is defined at the top)

Comment: And the error is...? Did you try `('item-' + s)` in parentheses?

Comment: I'd use `'item-{}'.format(s)` instead of `'item-' + s` too.

Comment: it's python 2 so i don't need parentheses the answer was a messing s after if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need check a specific variable or expression for membership in `consumables` in your `if` clause.

Probably you want: `if s not in consumables`

Comment: thanks man i knew it was simple but i just couldn't get it now it works